# MySQL AlphaID Function

Tags: mysql

While trying to optimize a few *queries* to not do with PHP something I could bring ready-to-use from database, I tried to convert [two routines](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1939c6e76d4bf400eb9b525a76dd2288) originally created in PHP to encode an integer in its *AlphaID* representation and then back, from string to integer.

Let's take a deep breath before this can be considered as a Stack Overflow question, I [asked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31052059#31052059) before posting

I tried to port them [by myself](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/561f860177e611014f89752f4558d710) but there were a few problems:

1. The original routine, in PHP, was able to encode correctly up to the maximum possible value fo a 32bits *integer* (2147483647), but for some reason my port stops earlier. I wasn't capable to debug further but in some moment after 2000000000 doesn't encode anymore.
2. Up to the point in which the function works, the encoding is always "one ahead', for example, encoding the *integer* **2**, instead of returning the expected **baaac** is resulting in **baaad**, the equivalent of the *integer* **3** when encoded

I've got suggestions to use AES_ENCRYPT() and its counterpart to decrypt, but that's not the purpose because what I really need, as a requirement of the project, is to display something better characterized as a PRIMARY KEY in a textual representation of letters and number (only!)

I also had suggestions to use hashing functions and I tested MD5(), SHA1() and all combinations of SHA2() but all of them result in very long strings which would be difficult to display on web environment.

And, of course, being able to do such conversion straight in the database would allow me to change INT for BIGINT and have up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 records.

So, that said, is there a way to represent *integer* as *AlphaID* with MSQL? Or something similar then, I'm open to suggestions.

If not something *built-in*, and maybe this could be considered as *off-topic*, how could I fix the implementations I made?

Comment: Integers already fit your requirement of "a textual representation of letters and number (only!)". Why do you need to bring letters into the mix? Why do you need to display meaningless (to the end user) numbers, or even more meaningless letters?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this with built-in functions would be to just convert the number into base 36:

```
mysql> select conv(9223372036854775807,10,36);
+---------------------------------+
| conv(9223372036854775807,10,36) |
+---------------------------------+
| 1Y2P0IJ32E8E7                   |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

This allows use of 0-9 A-Z, and is the largest base supported by `CONV()`.

To convert back:

```
mysql> select conv('1Y2P0IJ32E8E7', 36, 10);
+-------------------------------+
| conv('1Y2P0IJ32E8E7', 36, 10) |
+-------------------------------+
| 9223372036854775807           |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Documentation for `CONV` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv).

See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix), if you don't know how bases work.

Comment: Interesting, but with the data I have for now it seems to not have a fixed length. Although this approach does solve the issue, for initial records, with low IDs, looks weird to display one or two letters/numbers

Comment: Add a large(ish) number to each one then, solves that problem

Comment: But, in that case would be much better to use a GUID

Comment: Up to you. I've given you a easily-used alternative...